# Plasma Maintenance

Tags: plasma-physics

What are energy efficient ways that can be used to keep a plasma in its fully ionized mode while minimizing losses due to recombination?

Let’s say I have 1 mole of some material, and I need 15eV to ionize each molecule to produce the plasma, that would require me approx 1.5 MJ of energy. How can such a plasma be maintained for a few milliseconds at minimal input of energy at the same order of magnitude or less as the 1.5MJ energy input to produce the plasma?

For numerical purpose assume I have ion temperature ~500,000K and ion density 10^25 m^-3